# npm version update to specific version

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I want to update my local version, so I run 
npm version patch. this will update versions like this:
- 1.0.0 -> 1.0.1 -> 1.0.2 -> 1.0.3

I want to set specific version like 1.0.x , you have idea how to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

```
npm version ${newVersion} --no-git-tag-version
```

Comment: this worked for me, skipped the --no-git-tag-version flag because I actually want the tag

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a way to use

```
npm version patch <my version>
```

Disappointing **npm version** does not take an extra argument.

Instead I had to scrap the current version, split it, and update the patch myself before passing the result to npm version.

My Jenkinsfile uses something like

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    options {
        timestamps ()
    }
    stages {
        stage("Promote?") {
            when {
                branch 'master'
            }
            input {
                message "Create Installers?"
            }
            agent {
                label 'mac'
            }
            steps {
                obtainVersion()
            }
        }
        stage("Installers") {
            parallel {
                stage("OSx") {
                    agent {
                        label 'mac'
                    }
                    steps {
                        sh "npm version ${newVersion} --no-git-tag-version"
                    }
                }
                stage("Windows") {
                    agent {
                        label 'win'
                    }
                    steps {
                        bat "npm version ${newVersion} --no-git-tag-version"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Store the version for use when creating the installers
def newVersion;

def obtainVersion() {
    println "Obtaining the build version"
    def version = sh script:"node -p \"require('./package.json').version\"", returnStdout: true
    println "version in repo is ${version}"
    def versionParts = version.tokenize( '.' )
    newVersion = "${versionParts[0]}.${versionParts[1]}.${currentBuild.number}"
    println "new version for build is ${newVersion}"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all clean the NPM cache. You can do this using.

sudo npm cache clean -f

Install node helper (n) globally using following command.

sudo npm install -g n

Once node helper is installed. You can either get the latest stable version using

sudo n stable

Or if you want specific version like i needed 0.11.10 then you can do this using.

sudo n 0.11.10

After upgrade you can check the latest version of node using node –version or node -v.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to update my local package. I have project that need to upload it to local repository. so i want to set hardcoded the version number

Answer (score -1):

By default running `npm install <name>` will translate to `npm install <name>@latest` (or semver compatible version if ran in a folder with a package.json) you can choose the exact version with `npm install <name>@<version>` [doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Comment: I need to set the version local, to my local project, and not for installing specific version

Comment: Then use the exact `version` in your package.json instead of the "Compatible with version" : `^version` [doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies)
use `"foo": "1.0.1"` instead of `"foo": "^1.0.1"`

Comment: You can save the exact version when installing a module with the `--save-exact` option

Comment: He's talking about the package.json version of the project being developed. i.e. Not a dependency.

Comment: In this case you can use `npm version <newversion>`

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me when I needed to upgrade npm to a specific version, not just the latest version.

Use npm itself to upgrade/downgrade version

`npm install -g npm@<version>`